# how do I change a css property

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I need to change the color of the antd select.
[image]

In the above picture, I need to make changes to `ant-select-selection-item` but calling that as it is changes every antd select.
So, I have given a custom name to select,

```
             <Select
                className="mcq-selected-answer"
                mode="multiple"
                disabled={true}
                style={{ width: "100%", marginTop: "5px" }}
              >
               //Code
              </Select>
```

In the above, tried putting custom values (need to change color) as inline, but that would change it.
Also tried accessing the class,

```
.ant-select.mcq-selected-answer.ant-select-multiple.ant-select-disabled.ant-select-show-search.ant-select-selector.ant-select-selection-overflow.ant-select-selection-overflow-item.ant-select-selection-item {
  background-color: red;
}
```

but couldn't access the `ant-select-selection-item`.

Comment: Hi, are you using postCSS on your project ?

Comment: You could access them using .class.class i.e nested class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have your custom `className` you can change the `ant-select-selection-item` using the following:

```
.mcq-selected-answer .ant-select-selection-item {
  background: red;
}
```

In your codesandbox example, in order for the border to be in effect, you need to provide a more "precise" css path

```
.mcq-selected-answer .ant-select-selection-overflow-item .ant-select-selection-item {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-select-forked-73lduw?file=/src/styles.css:0-70)

Comment: Tried adding `border: 1px solid blue;` it doesn't work

Comment: just added it. it works. refresh the sandbox. maybe you need sth else?

Comment: In my case, the select is in disabled state. Yes, `.mcq-selected-answer .ant-select-selection-item {
  background: red;
}` works. but added `border: 1px solid blue` doesn't work. But trying that with devtool i.e element it work, but not in css file.

Comment: changed the sandbox to be in disabled state. also added second border in parent element. cant see the problem TBH.

Comment: Code sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-4-20-5-forked-1dk0ft?file=/index.css

Comment: check my updated answer